# Cache a constant value

Tags: python

I am developing an application for color blind people to enable them smoothly surf the Internet. I have a set of colors, lets say A , which consists of all the colors seen by a color blind person. Set A is calculated using a big calculation involving millions of colors. Set A is independent of inputs taken in my application i.e set A is like a 'constant' to me (just like 'pi' in mathematics). Now I want to store set A so that whenever I run my application, it is available without any added computational cost i.e i don't have to calculate A every time I run my application.

My Try:
I think this can be done by building a class having one constant but can it be done without creating any special class for just a constant?

I am using Python!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a class. You want to store the calculated values on disk and load them back again on startup: for that you will want to look into the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) or [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can certainly do this with Python

If your constant was just a number -- say, you had just discovered [tau](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG7vhMMXagQ) -- then you would just declare it in a module, and import that module in all of your other source files:

constants.py:

```
# Define my new super-useful number
TAU = 6.28318530718
```

everywhere else:

```
from constants import TAU # Look, no calculations!
```

Expanding a bit, if you had a more complicated structure, like a dictionary, that took you a long time to compute, then you could just declare that in your module instead:

constants.py:

```
# Verified results of the national survey
PEPSI_CHALLENGE = {
    'Pepsi': 0.57,
    'Coke': 0.43,
}
```

And you can do this for more and more complicated data. The problem, eventually, is that just writing your constants module gets harder and harder, the more complex your data is, and it can be especially hard to update if you occasionally recompute the value you want to cache. In that case, you want to look at [pickling](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html) the data, possibly as the final step of a python script which calculates it, and then load that data in a module that you import.

To do that, import pickle, and dump a single object out to a disk file:

recalculate.py:

```
# Here is the script that computes a small value from the hugely complicated domain:
import random
from itertools import groupby
import pickle

# Collect all of the random numbers
random_numbers = [random.randint(0,10) for r in xrange(1000000)]

# TODO: Check this -- this should definitely be 7
most_popular = max(groupby(sorted(random_numbers)),
                           key=lambda(x, v):(len(list(v)),-L.index(x)))[0]

# Now save the most common random number to disk, using pickle
# Almost any object is picklable like this, but check the docs for the exact details
pickle.dump(most_popular, open('data_cache','w'))
```

Now, in your constants file, you can simply read the pickled data from the file on disk, and have it available without recalculating it:

constants.py:

```
import pickle

most_popular = pickle.load(open('data_cache'))
```

everywhere else:

```
from constants import most_popular
```